# Do the SQL Server 2019 cumulative updates apply to the Express edition?

Tags: sql-server-express

This [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/latest-updates-for-microsoft-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) lists all the cumulative updates that are available for the different versions of SQL Server. But it is not entirely clear to me whether the updates apply only to SQL Server 2019 (the main edition) or to the Express edition as well.

Is it safe to run the cumulative update for the Express edition of SQL Server 2019?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference in service packs or cumulative updates between
all editions of SQL Server : Express, developer, standard or enterprise.

Patches said to be specifically for SQL Server Express are usually
complete versions rather than patches.

If Express was installed as a dependency by a third-party product,
Microsoft patches may not be able to detect it.
It is also possible that the third-party product will not work without
the exact version that it itself installed.

In any case, the update will not run if it cannot find an installed compatible product.